# Shiny R renderDataTable with null table

Tags: r, shiny

What is the best way to only render a data table in shiny if data exists?  Right now, I am getting the following error because I am telling shiny to render a data table, even when it is NULL.

```
    Warning in file(file, "rt") :
    cannot open file '\': No such file or directory
    Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
```

My code is split like this, where I read the data once the user chooses a csv file.  After a user chooses a csv file, the error goes away and everything works fine.  How do I tell Shiny to not display a data table until a valid file is chosen?

```
filedata <- reactive({
  if (is.null(input$file_selector)){
    # User has not uploaded a file yet
    return(NULL)
  } else {
  read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben'), file_dir()),'\\',input$file_selector),skip=1)}
})

output$filetable <- renderDataTable({
  filedata()
})
```

I've tried putting the output$filetable <- .... code after the read.csv... line in the filedata <- ... function, but that doesn't work either.  What else should I be doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use req() function, this will check whether the file the file is present or not then it will go to the proceding code

```
filedata <- reactive({
  file <-input$file_selector
  req(file)
  read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben'), file_dir()),'\\',file),skip=1)}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `req()`, as shown below

```
filedata <- reactive({
  req(input$file_selector)
  read.csv(paste0(parseDirPath(c(home = 'C:\\Users\\Ruben'), file_dir()),'\\',input$file_selector),skip=1)
})
```